# Use PIL to create new image that is a specific size

Tags: python, size, png, python-imaging-library, pixel

I am trying to find the exact pixel height and length of a piece of red text on an blank black image. To do this I am taking the pixel values of the red colours and copying and pasting it into a x,y matrix. I then create a new image and paste the results. However, I cannot get the size of the output image to be EXACTLY the height and length of the text that's extracted.

```
img = Image.open("word.png")
img = img.convert("P")
his = img.histogram()

values = {}
for i in range(256):
values[i] = his[i]

for j,k in sorted(values.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:10]:
print j,k

img2  = Image.new("P",img.size,255) #THIS SIZE MODE IS WHAT I CAN'T FIX
img = img.convert("P")

temp = {}
for x in range(img.size[1]):
for y in range(img.size[0]):
    pix = img.getpixel((y,x))
    temp[pix] = pix
    if pix == 15 or pix == 11 or pix == 12 or pix == 14:
        img2.putpixel((y,x),0)
img2.save("output.png")
```

In the bit that I have commented:

If I put (0,0) as a blank canvas, it says "image index out of range".

If I put nothing it doesn't work (it needs a size there).

img.size just uses the size from the first img.

If anyone has a better method of doing this whole thing feel free to tell me. All I am trying to do is get the pixel height/length of a word in a specific font+size so I can store it in a database.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help (its indented on this i don't know why it isn't in the code)

Comment: this is solved no need to do this anymore thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are trying to solve sounds like you want to size your image to a certain size but don't know what that size is in advance.

PIL does not support dynamically sized images, so you would need to create the larger image as you did and then crop it using the img.crop method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are 100% correct. I cannot crop it though as I do not know the size in x vs y pixels. This is the problem I face.